# make file size at least 1MB

Tags: ubuntu, bash, virtualbox, bash-scripting, binary-files

I'm trying to learn about operating systems by making one myself and testing it in virtual-box, but `VBoxManage convertfromraw` doesn't allow my source file to be very tiny (512B).

Are there any bash commands that will do the following (pseudo-code), while still keeping the contents of the file?

```
if (FILE.size < 1MB) {
    FILE.resize(1MB);
}
```

Comment: What do you want to add to the end of the file when making it bigger? Null bytes (0x00)? Random data? Arbitrary data/don't care?

Comment: "Arbitrary data/don't care", it's just to make `VBoxManage` happy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming Linux and a modern filesystem (safe – only grows files):

```
fallocate --length=1M yourfile
```

Without fallocate (creates a *sparse* file when growing; be careful with size):

```
truncate --size=1M yourfile
```

Without fallocate (requires a 64-bit system for files over 2 GB):

```
file="yourfile"
want=$(( 1 * 1024 * 1024 ))

size=$(stat -c %s "$file")
if (( want > size )); then
    head -c $(( want - size )) /dev/zero >> "$file"
fi
```

Comment: Yes, i do indeed use linux, with the ext4 filesystem, and the first option gives an error. The third option works, but not in with Makefile. The second option works perfectly, thanks!

Comment: That's unusual, ext4 has supported fallocate() for years.

Comment: `fallocate: temp/OS.bin: fallocate failed: Operation not supported`

Answer (score 0):

From [another thread](https://serverfault.com/questions/343705/how-do-i-append-a-specific-number-of-null-bytes-to-a-file):

> ```
> dd if=/dev/zero bs=1 count=NUMBER >> yourfile
> ```
>
> This will read from `/dev/zero` and append to `yourfile` `NUMBER` bytes.

Comment: This technically isn't what i asked for, but it works...
Is it possible to subtract the current file size from 1MB and use that as count?

Comment: Yes. `bs` is block size. And it outputs count times block size.   So reduce count to (target size minus size it already is).